# Adding rating and review capability inside an app

Tags: ios

I am using this `SKStoreReviewController` to add rating and review to my app. But there is one thing I am confused about.

As an example, lets say the popup will appear after 30 days. In the 30th day the popup will appear every time for one particular user or just once ?

Is `Apple` taking care to not show the popup to same user multiple times in a day or I have to add the logic inside code for myself ?

Comment: I think Apple is going to take care of showing to user

Comment: I understand this. But lets say the popup appears when u open the app. If the user submitted the review, will the popup appear again for that user in that day ?

Comment: No. I don't think it will appear again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can trigger when to show the Rating view by calling this method: `requestReview()`

However, it's **not guaranteed that it will show/ask the user for rating**. It's completely governed by apple. You can check lines from Apple docs related to the same.

**Excerpt from Apple docs.**

> Although you should call this method when it makes sense in the user
>   experience flow of your app, the actual display of a rating/review
>   request view is governed by App Store policy. Because this method may
>   or may not present an alert, it's not appropriate to call it in
>   response to a button tap or other user action.

Answer (score 0):

Apple is taking care of it. Have a look at [`requestReview()`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/storekit/skstorereviewcontroller/2851536-requestreview) method of the `SKStoreReviewController`. A call to this method may or may not present an alert to review.

Answer (score 0):

There is not much details provided by Apple for this. But in one of the docs Apple do quote that the developer should handle the flow and logic to display the popup. But again weather that popup is shown or not its upon Apple.

[Apple Docs:](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/storekit/skstorereviewcontroller/2851536-requestreview?changes=_2)

> Although you should call this method when it makes sense in the user experience flow of your app, the actual display of a rating/review request view is governed by App Store policy. Because this method may or may not present an alert, it's not appropriate to call it in response to a button tap or other user action.

The following are some apparently useful points listed in [this medium article](https://medium.com/@kavithakumarasamy89/skstorereviewcontroller-apple-way-to-request-review-and-rating-inside-ios-app-in-ios-10-3-453a6f897e9d)(Though the source it mentions have no details of the sorts):

1. You should only call request review when it makes sense in the user experience flow of your app, and then call the method only after the user has demonstrated some engagements on an app.
2. You have no control over exactly what’s happening and the dialog displayed or its callbacks, that is determined entirely by the system.
3. The system may or may not show a rating prompt, it’s not appropriate to call the API in response to a button tap or other user action because it is not going to happen every time.
4. No matter how many times you call the API, the system will only show up to a maximum of 3 prompts to the same user in a 365-day period.
5. The App Store defaults to showing ratings and reviews only for your app’s most recent version.
6. The User can turn off this in settings.
7. Apple might mandate this flow in future.

Hope this helps.